# How to run the node mailer in web host server

Tags: angular, nodemailer

I have created a page for sending the form data to the gmail account using node mailer.

To send the page form data to gmail i have to run the server first `node server.js` where i configured the node mailer. It is working great as expected in local but not in production site.

It is very clear after run the server.js only this works.

But how do I start the `node server.js` from web hosting server to make it work in production site.

Is there any different configuration for production like in local as mentioned below to start the server,

**server.js**

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const xoauth2 = require("xoauth2");
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Accept, Authorization');
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
//   next();
// });

app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));

app.post('/sendFormData', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body, 'data of form');
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    secure: 'true',
    port: '465',
    auth: {
      user: 'test@gmail.com', // must be Gmail
      pass: 'pass'
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: `${req.body.email}`,
    to: 'test@gmail.com', // must be Gmail
    cc: `${req.body.name}`,
    subject: 'New Order',
    html: `
            <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #6c0078">
              <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #6c0078; color: #fff;">
                  <th style="padding: 10px 0">Name</th>                 
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #6c0078;">${req.body.name}</td>                 

                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          `
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'successfuly sent!'
      })
    }
  });

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server run!!!");
});
```

**Error from production site**

[image]

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: Form data is not receiving to gmail account when I send from production site. But in local it is working fine after start the server.js

Comment: are you able to reach to the server api ? and have you checked server logs?

Comment: No errors in server logs.  There is no server API, have to call server.js for nodemailer.

Comment: can you add the endpoint you are using ?

Comment: Hi. did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue. I put the server.js file in the dist file that was created after building an Angular app and it does not work. I also wrote http://serverIp:3000/sendFormData.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your endpoint looks like `http://serverIp:3000/sendFormData`.
You can also add error response.

```
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
       error
       });
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'successfuly sent!'
      })
    }
  });
```

Comment: in your form action use this url.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is not working. I think we have to configure node mailer for server separately if I'm not wrong.